# CSS: how to cut everything out of the body?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a website, the first image is the result I get now. what I want is to cut everything out of the body edge. Result will be as the 2nd image. so I add "overflow-x" into the body CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #101113;
}
```

But it doesn't work.  how can I make change to get that result?  Is it possible? Thanks.

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRYVa.png)

[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onjuM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the element that's overflowing and add
`max-width: 100%`

If it still doesn't work, try adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the `html` tag.

And secondly, why are you using max-width on the body tag?

Comment: Just the layout design can't handle window size larger than 1200px.

Comment: @Ken then better wrap it in a container and set the width for it to 1200px. Afterwards just center it. Not a good practice to set max-width on the body tag.